# Definindo um middleware para um controller, exceto uma função no Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Estou começando a trabalhar agora com Laravel e percebi que definido as rotas diretamente para os controles onde eu posso definir o tipo de request HTTP é mais viável para a minha aplicação. Hoje tenho algo assim:

**routes.php**

```
Route::controller("usuario","UsuarioController");
```

**UsuarioController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class UsuarioController extends Controller 
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        //$this->middleware("auth");
    }
    public function getAutenticar() 
    {
        return view("Usuario/Autenticar");
    }
}
```

Minha dúvida é a seguinte. Existe alguma forma de eu definir um middleware manual dentro do controle onde apenas para 2 rotas eu estaria livre do middleware auth?

Eu sei que se eu definir essas rotas manualmente no arquivo `routes.php` funciona mas, fazendo isso não posso continuar trabalhando usando a definição de tipo de request HTTP dentro do meu controller.

Consigo, de alguma forma forçar que meu controller aceite 2 middlewares, 1 para "x" métodos e outra para os outros métodos?

Comment: Qual foi o motivo do negativo? Poderiam informar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existem outras formas de definir um `middleware` no Laravel, mas vou mostrar da forma que você precisa, que é definindo diretamente no Controller.

## Opção `except`

Para definir um `middleware` específico para um controller, basta utilizar a opção `except`, para você definir quais são os métodos que você não deseja aplicar o `middleware` específico:

Veja:

```
$this->middleware('meu_middleware', ['except' => 'logout']);
```

`except` significa "exceto". Significa que tudo que for passado por parâmetro, será ignorado para aquele middleware.

É possível também passar mais de um valor que serão ignorados:

```
$this->middleware('meu_middleware', ['except' => ['logout', 'register']]);
```

## Opção `only`

Se você precisa apenas definir onde o middleware será aplicado (ao invés de aplicar as exceções), você  pode usar a opção `only` - significa "apenas".

Veja:

```
 $this->middleware('meu_middleware', ['only' => ['listar', 'deletar']]);
```

Comment: excelente! isso funcionou exatamente como eu precisava... ja tava até pensando em criar outra classe desnecessária para separar as funções sendo que é tudo método de 1 só